# C# how to get value from another class?

Tags: c#

This is my Main.xaml.cs

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    User u = new User();
    u.id = 1;
    u.access = 2;
    u.username = "USER1";

}
```

This is User.cs

```
class User
{
    public int id;
    public int access;
    public string username;

    public int ID
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }

    public int Access
    {
        get { return access; }
        set { access = value; }
    }

    public string Username
    {
        get { return username; }
        set { username = value; }
    }

}
```

**Aim:**

I have created another button in Main.xaml.cs:

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    User u = new User();
    MessageBox.Show(u.Username.ToString());
}
```

I am aiming to get the value from `User.cs` that I previously assigned in other button. `Button_Click`.

How can I show messagebox with values assigned to `User.cs`?

Comment: In that first button-click, you are creating a user, and forgetting about it when it goes out of scope (the method ends). In the second one, you are creating a *new* user that is not related in any way to the first. And has a `null` Username

Comment: OT when you use properties with explicit backing fields, those fields should be `private`

Comment: @HansKeﬆing I see. I got the idea totally wrong then using `new User();` in both button clicks

Comment: The first use is fine, although the scope of the variable should probably be class-level. The second one you don't want - you want to use the value that is set before

Comment: That awkward moment when everyone starts writing the answer at the same time, and as soon as finishes, discovers, that everyone else did the same :p :D

Answer (score 2):

In your code you are creating 2 different objects.

Try this way:

```
User _user = new User();

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    _user.id = 1;
    _user.access = 2;
    _user.username = "USER1";

}

private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(_user.Username);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for an asnwer! how come you are using `_` undelrine before variable?

Comment: Just a naming convention, you can avoid it

Comment: Love that ! - :D

Comment: Just if I can give you an advice, avoid naming variables with single letters or names without meaning, usually we tend to use a name with a specific meaning to understand code even after years

Answer (score 1):

Your variables are local variables only visible in the methods where you declare them. Instead, declare your user variable in your class:

```
class Main
 {
 private User user;

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    user = new User();
    user.id = 1;
    user.access = 2;
    user.username = "USER1";

}

private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(user == null)
     {
      MessageBox.Show("create user first");
      }
     else
     {
    MessageBox.Show(user.Username.ToString());
    }
}
}
```

Now both methods will use the same instance of your User class.

By the way, you can use auto properties in your user class. It is easier to type and less error prone:

```
class User
 {
 public int ID {get; set; }
 public int Access {get;set;}
 public string Username {get;set;}
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you are creating an object in the scope of `Button_Click`,
which then is not available to the outer scopes.

To solve the problem you can simply move out the declaration of the `User` object outside,
and in the meethods, simply assign values to them.

Here is a solution based on your code:

```
using System;


class User
{
    public int id;
    public int access;
    public string username;

    public int ID
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }

    public int Access
    {
        get { return access; }
        set { access = value; }
    }

    public string Username
    {
        get { return username; }
        set { username = value; }
    }
}

public class Program
{
    User u; // Moved the object outside the method.

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        u = new User(); // Assigned value
        u.id = 1;
        u.access = 2;
        u.username = "USER1";
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // User u = new User(); //  No need of this
        MessageBox.Show(u.Username.ToString());
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    }
}
```